# JOLT: Normalize JSON

Tags: json, jolt

i am new to JOLT and just can't understand the syntax regarding lists.
I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "Country": [
    {
      "Name": "Angola",
      "AnimalNames.AnimalName": [
        "Aspidelaps lubricus",
        "Atheris squamigera",
        "Atractaspis bibronii"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Argentina",
      "AnimalNames.AnimalName": [
        "Apis mellifera scutellata",
        "Bothrops alternatus",
        "Bothrops ammodytoides"
      ]
    }    
  ]
}
```

Desired Output:

```json
[
   {
      "country_name":"Angola",
      "species":"Aspidelaps lubricus"
   },
   {
      "country_name":"Angola",
      "species":"Atheris squamigera"
   },
   {
      "country_name":"Angola",
      "species":"Atractaspis bibronii"
   },
   {
      "country_name":"Argentina",
      "species":"Apis mellifera scutellata"
   },
   {
      "country_name":"Argentina",
      "species":"Bothrops alternatus"
   },
   {
      "country_name":"Argentina",
      "species":"Bothrops ammodytoides"
   }
]
```

All my attempts just gave me a list of all countries and a list of all species..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation specs as in the explained manner

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Country": {
        "*": { // level of the indexes of the "Country" array        
          "AnimalNames*": { // represents the key-value pair(attribute,object or array) starting with animal
            "*": { // the indexes of the current array(if it was an object this level wouldn't exist)
              "@(2,Name)": "@(3,Name)[&1].country_name", // group by the countries and their respective sub-indexes within the arrays where "@(2,Name)" represents going two levels up the tree and grabbing the value of "Name" attribute
              "@": "@(3,Name)[&1].species" // go three levels up the tree by traversing : and double { in order to reach the level of the Country Name while indexing with "AnimalNames.AnimalName" arrays by [&1] to go one level up as keeping array style by square brackets and "species" is a fixed tag name 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of the array tags
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```